# Re-download macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta

Tags: macos, beta, catalina

Is there a way to re-download macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS that you are running currently?

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to download Catalina from the Mac App Store: [macOS Catalina Beta](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/macos-catalina-beta/id1455661060?mt=12)
[image]
Credit to [Thomas Nelson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364457/197131) for finding the Mac App Store download link.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and install the macOS Catalina beta profile.

Now on your Mac running a public release of macOS, go to System Preferences → Software Update. You'll get prompted to install macOS Catalina 10.15 beta.

Choose to install it, and it will download the macOS Catalina installer under your `/Applications` directory.

Comment: Hey thanks - already running 10.15 and want to re-install - but the access utility will only tell me that the system is up to date - Is there a way to force a re-download of the installer?

Comment: @WesWynens I guess you'll need access to a Mac running an earlier version of macOS to download the full installer.

Comment: @WesWynens Just in case if may end up working, you can go to Mac App Store and search for Catalina and see if it shows up (it's unlikely, but may work). If yes, you can download the installer from there.

Comment: @WesWynens I guess you are looking to perform a fresh install of the macOS Catalina. One approach that I can suggest (although slightly tedious) is to restore the current public release of macOS (i.e. macOS Mojave 10.14.5) via Internet recovery and use it to download the installer for macOS Catalina. You can keep the installer for macOS Catalina aside (on a USB drive). Also, consider installing and running the macOS Catalina beta off of an external drive.

Answer (score 1):

You have Mac OS Catalina it means you have a developer account or the profile to download the beta of the OS. Use the same profile to download the OS again.

For the first time when you download the profile and when system will check for update, it will give you errors like,

System is up to date.
Or 
No update found.

Just keep on on clicking re try or ok and it will keep on checking again after 2 or 3 times it will start downloading.

[image]

Look at image iam running on the latest beta version of Catalina /
and still able to download the the same Version .

I also needed to re download the OS as iam about to change my Macs SDD to 1tb and I need to make an offline installer

Answer (score -1):

You can re-download installer apps by launching a URI.

For example, to download the Monterey Public Beta, you can run this in a shell, or simply click [this link](http://x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate?client=bau&installMajorOSBundle=com.apple.InstallAssistant.Seed.macOS12Seed1):

```sh
/usr/bin/open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate?client=bau&installMajorOSBundle=com.apple.InstallAssistant.Seed.macOS12Seed1"
```

The `installMajorOSBundle` value can be found at the `IASUBundleID` key in this [plist](https://configuration.apple.com/configurations/macos/seeding/content/content-1.0.plist).

The Public Beta Access Utility does this with a script (`zopenmas`).

Comment: Why the downvote?