# Cannot install macOS Beta version on MacBook Pro July 2019

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, catalina

I just got the new MacBook Pro, which was released few days ago. It is running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

I am trying to install macOS Catalina beta version, either beta or developer beta. I have installed both profiles separately to try, however I get the following error.

I even did a fresh installation of macOS Mojave just to make sure something was not wrong with the installed OS that came with the machine.

Is it because the machine is too new and not recognized? If so, I doubt it as I see this machine in the supported devices for the beta version on Apple's support: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201300

Any idea why am I not being able to install a Beta version of any kind?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What did it say underneath that not found dialog? Mine says "Your Mac is up to date — macOS Mojave Beta 10.14.6 (currently pb3, released this week) - but this machine cannot do Catalina. Also, what do you have set in Advanced... ?

Comment: @Tetsujin At least you've got the 10.14.6, I can't even get to that...I attached 2 more screenshots.

Comment: I'd make sure you follow this - https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/install-the-macos-catalina-public-beta/ - I can't check it as I have a building full of Mac Pros.. which have been dumped at Catalina :\

Comment: Yes I tried that, no luck... I'm trying to find a direct link to Catalina beta so I can install it through a bootable disk.

Comment: You won't find any OS directly from Apple that "just anyone" can download, ever. They just don't operate that way. You'd have to find a dodgy illicit mirror.

Comment: @Tetsujin telling anyone to go for a "dodgy illicit mirror" is really bad advice.

Comment: @benwiggy - I'm pretty sure I wasn't advising anyone to do that. The very term 'dodgy illicit mirror' ought to tell you that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this...
[Catalina Link to App Store](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/macos-catalina-beta/id1455661060?mt=12)

Edit:  This link now downloads beta 5.

It may help trigger the search for updates but it didn't fix the issue for me either.

Update:  I ran the App Store link on my iMac that already has Catalina.  App Store opened System Preferences and asked if I wanted to download Catalina.  I answered yes and that downloaded the full installer.

From there I made the thumb drive from the command line and when I booted off the thumb drive it tells me that a software update is required for this Mac and clicking software update tells me that there is no update.

Running the installer from within Mojave tells me that "This version of macOS 10.15 cannot be installed on this computer."[image: Catalina Beta Screenshot]

Apparently the laptop is really unsupported at this point.

Comment: Oh I see. Good job finding the app store link. I did the steps earlier you mentioned and I've got the same issue with "cannot be installed on this computer". What Macbook pro are you on?

Comment: 13" 128 GB 2019 base model. It is interesting how the latest OS isn't ready for the latest computer isn't it?

Comment: @Nima Just ran Software Update and 10.14.6 beta 4 appeared tonight.  Just wondering if this appeared for you as well.

Comment: Indeed - I've seen it last night. So I assume they are still testing the Catalina's beta version on this machine. I've got the same specs as yours btw.

Comment: Catalina Beta just arrived on my MacBook Pro today.  Its kind of like Christmas. :-D

Comment: Lol, same here, so sneaky of Apple!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, finally! https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/clb8at/the_requested_version_of_macos_is_not_available/

Execute this command in your terminal:

> ```
> sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --set-catalog https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15beta-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
> ```

Then, delete the current file in case there is any:

> ```
> sudo rm /Users/Shared/.SeedEnrollment.plist
> ```

Make a new file using nano:

> ```
> sudo nano /Users/Shared/.SeedEnrollment.plist
> ```

Copy paste this in it, then save the file and you can finally see the update.

> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>     <key>SeedProgram</key>
>     <string>PublicSeed</string>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Done, sorry... Is it okay now ?

Comment: Excellent, I’ve also included the linked file content rather than depending on another external link, and added quote formatting for the quoted content. +1’d

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still struggles with this, if you have more than one user run on your Mac.

1. Open `/Users` in the Finder and `right-click > Get Info`.
2. Change permission settings to `Read & Write`. (If you have 3 users then change all 3)
   [image]
3. `Setting Icon > Apply to enclosed items`
   [image]
4. Redo answer from `Lounès KSOURI`. (Or just check the software update again)

(That how I solved my problem, maybe a bit inappropriate but it just works)